# Creating surface in matplotlib throw on lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to create curved surface throw on 3 lines.
Each line is defined in 3 points( each point have coordinate(x, y, z) )

first line:
(0, 0, 10)
(0, 5, 5)
(0, 10, 2)

second line:
(2, 0, 10)
(2, 5, 5)
(2, 10, 2)

third line:
(4, 1, 10)
(4, 6, 5)
(4, 11, 2)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]
y = [0, 0, 1, 5, 5, 6, 10, 10, 11]
z = [10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]

X = x
Y = y
Z = z

Y, X = np.meshgrid(Y, X)
ax.plot_wireframe( X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting this image
[image: my actual image]

But I need image like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

plot_trisurf is resolved my issue.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]
y = [0, 0, 1, 5, 5, 6, 10, 10, 11]
z = [10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]

X = x
Y = y
Z = z

ax.plot_trisurf( X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]